# Count the number of objects in another model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models in different apps: Program in programs and Contact in contacts. Each program can have many contacts. I want to have a field in Program called database_quantity that shows how many contacts are associated with that program. Here is what I have tried so far which is giving me this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Contact'. I think this has to do with circular referencing but I am lost with how to proceed.

programs models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from contacts.models import Contact

class Program(models.Model):
    program_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    program_format = models.ForeignKey(ProgramFormat, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    program_type = models.ForeignKey(ProgramType, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    program_board = models.ForeignKey(RealEstateBoard, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    article_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ArticleContentType, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_database_quantity(self):
        database_quantity = Contact.objects.all().filter(Contact.author=Program.client)

        return database_quantity

    database_quantity = property(get_database_quantity)
```

contacts models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from programs.models import Program

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Last Name', blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    program_code = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
```

Settings Installed Apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'contacts.apps.ContactsConfig',
    'programs.apps.ProgramsConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'import_export',
]
```

contacts apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ContactsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'contacts'
```

Comment: show me installed_app in settings.py

Comment: I just added it to the end

Comment: and show me `contacts.apps.ContactsConfig`

Comment: added it, is that the right bit?

Comment: I love to help. please can you break the description of what you want exaclty...do you want to use info on Contact table to get that of program table and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You can define your ForeignKey mappings with strings instead of Model references, like this:

```
program_code = models.ForeignKey('programs.Program', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
```

So that you won't need to import a model from another app into models.py

2 - You have several problems in your **get_database_quantity** method, you need to filter with model instance, not model Class, i.e self.client instead of Program.client. Also you shouldn't filter like **Contact.author=...**, it should be like **author=...**. And, to get quantity, you need **.count()** method of querysets. Finally, you can import other model locally to avoid circular import issues.

```
def get_database_quantity(self):
    from contacts.models import Contact
    database_quantity = Contact.objects.filter(author=self.client).count()

    return database_quantity
```

3 - You can also write get_database_quantity like this:

```
 def get_database_quantity(self):
    return self.client.contacts.count()
```

If you define your related ForeignKey field like this:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contacts')
```

Comment: Thank you that's awesome and it's working - but what it's showing me is the total number of contacts for that user, not that program. What I need is something like this: database_quantity = Contact.objects.filter(author=self.client).filter(program_code=self.program_code).count()  I just want the number of contacts for each specific program. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: with my example above

Comment: Contact.objects.filter(author__program=self).count() should give what you want

Comment: That is returning the total number of contacts for that user, not the program itself

Comment: This should return #of contacts for program actually, maybe you need to run it with distinct, like: Contact.objects.filter(author__program=self).distinct().count()

Comment: I set this up in admin to view it: https://imgur.com/a/A1rIveV  A contact is assigned to K0001 and K0003 but in Programs they are both being counted. It should be 1 for each.

Comment: By the way, with your model structure, a program has 1 client, and a client has multiple contacts. So how does number of contacts for program.client differ from number of contacts for program?

Comment: Hmm you have a direct relationship between a program and contact, so you can go with Contact.objects.filter(program_code=self).count()

Comment: Maybe thats where I went wrong. Should I have the Contact below to the Program and the Program below to the User?